# Get url/link to latest comments in a post

Tags: posts, comments

I have a post list in WordPress where people can see the most recently commented posts. They will appear above the list. That's fine, but now, I have 300 comments on the same posts and I don't want the people to go scroll fully down when they want to read the newest comments.

Therefore I am asking if it's possible to get the url to the most recent commented posts on a particular day? For instance, my post list is updated if there is made a comment. On a day, they comment 30 times... I want a link to the **first** of this 30 comments, so that they can read from there, instead of scrolling down 270 other comments.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Edit: still nothing?

Comment: Have you tried using the [get_comments()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) WordPress function?

Comment: Will that get the post link with the latest comments that are posted that day? I don't think so... Tried it, yes.